# How does the equivalence part work?

Tags: derivatives, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

Considering now a random variable X with a geometric distribution with parameter p > 0, we have
$$E(X) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty kp(1-p)^{k-1} $$
We already shown that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty p(1-p)^{k-1} =1 $$
Which implies
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-p)^{k-1}=1/p $$
If we take the derivative on p we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty(k-1)(-1)(1-p)^{k-2}=-1/p^2$$
which is equivalent to
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(1-p)^{k-1}=1/p^2 $$

I know this is a silly question, but I couldnt get the equivalent part how is$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(1-p)^{k-1}$$ is equivalent to$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty(k-1)(-1)(1-p)^{k-2}$$  it will be much appreciated if someone explain on how they are equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(1-p)^{k-1} = {} & 1(1-p)^0 + 2(1-p)^1 \\ & {} + 3(1-p)^2 + 4(1-p)^3+\cdots \\[12pt]
\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k-1)(1-p)^{k-2} = {} & 0(1-p)^{-1} \\
& {} + 1(1-p)^0 + 2(1-p)^1 \\[8pt]
& {} + 3(1-p)^2 + 4(1-p)^3 + \cdots
\end{align}